# Android Encode h264 using libavcodec for ARGB

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, argb

I have a stream of buffer content which actually contains 480x800 sized ARGB image[byte array of size 480*800*4]. i want to encode around 10,000s of similar images into a stream of h.264 at specified fps(12). [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/api-example_8c-source.html) shows how to encode images into encoded video,but requires input to be yuv420.

Now i have ARGB images, i want to encode into CODEC_ID_H264
 [How to convert RGB from YUV420p for ffmpeg encoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667687/how-to-convert-rgb-from-yuv420p-for-ffmpeg-encoder) shows how to do it for rgb24, but how to do it for rgb32,meaning ARGB image data

how do i use libavcodec for this?

EDIT: i found [How to convert RGB from YUV420p for ffmpeg encoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667687/how-to-convert-rgb-from-yuv420p-for-ffmpeg-encoder)
But i don't understand.

From the 1st link, i come to know that AVFrame struct contains data[0],data[1](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/api-example_8c-source.html),data[2] which are filled with Y, U & V values.

In 2nd link, they showed how to use sws_scale to convert RGB24 to YUV420 as such

```
SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext(imgWidth, imgHeight,
                              AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, imgWidth, imgHeight,
                              AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 0, 0, 0, 0);
uint8_t * inData[1] = { rgb24Data }; // RGB24 have one plane
int inLinesize[1] = { 3*imgWidth }; // RGB stride
sws_scale(ctx, inData, inLinesize, 0, imgHeight, dst_picture.data, dst_picture.linesize)
```

Here i assume that rgb24Data is the buffer containing RGB24 image bytes.

So how i use this information for ARGB, which is 32 bit? Do i need manually to strip-off the alpha channel or any other work around ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just switch out the pixelformat and line stride from RGB24 to ARGB

```
SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext(imgWidth, imgHeight,
                              AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB, imgWidth, imgHeight,
                              AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 0, 0, 0, 0);
uint8_t * inData[1] = { rgb24Data }; // RGB24 have one plane
int inLinesize[1] = { 4*imgWidth }; // RGB stride
sws_scale(ctx, inData, inLinesize, 0, imgHeight, dst_picture.data, dst_picture.linesize)
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this and update. Also, this means i can try AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565 if my input is RGB565, does sws_scale supports RGB565 too?

Comment: During compile, i get , unknown type name `SwsContext` though i included swscale.h

Comment: That should get its own question.

Comment: Using `struct SwsContext` solved this! But i dnt know what happened.

Comment: structs are not automatically types in pure C.

Comment: hi,, in file `libx264.c`, see line 146. So which is right? `inData[1] = { rgb24Data };` or `inData[4] = { rgb24Data, NULL, NULL, NULL };`

Comment: Both are Ok. RGB is not a planar format (the three color planes are interleaved). So sws_scale, only uses the first pointer. If you were using a planar format such as YUV420P, you would need to fill in the other pointers.

Comment: I had to switch AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB to AV_PIX_FMT_RGB for transformation to work right.

Comment: @szatmary Hi how to do the reverse? I mean conversion from AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P to AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB using sws_scale.

Comment: Switch the source and destination.