# FFMPEG Encoding Issues

Tags: c++, video, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264

I am having issues encoding screen captures, into a h.264 file for viewing. The program below is cobbled together from examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914012/encoding-a-screenshot-into-a-video-using-ffmpeg) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/shotscreens/source/browse/record_video/record_video/recorder_fun.c?name=default&r=6d9a760112bc71c416f270a3d726c5cd8104c762). The first example, uses an older version of the ffmpeg api. So I tried to update that example for use in my program. The file is created and has something written to it, but when I view the file. The encoded images are all distorted. I am able to run the video encoding example from the ffmpeg api successfully. This is my first time posting, so if I missed anything please let me know.

I appreciate any assistance that is given.

My program:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <dwmapi.h>

extern "C"{
#include <stdint.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
}

using namespace std;

void ScreenShot(const char* BmpName, uint8_t *frame)
{
    HWND DesktopHwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    RECT DesktopParams;
    HDC DevC = GetDC(DesktopHwnd);
    GetWindowRect(DesktopHwnd,&DesktopParams);
    DWORD Width = DesktopParams.right - DesktopParams.left;
    DWORD Height = DesktopParams.bottom - DesktopParams.top;

    DWORD FileSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)+1*(Width*Height*4));
    char *BmpFileData = (char*)GlobalAlloc(0x0040,FileSize);

    PBITMAPFILEHEADER BFileHeader = (PBITMAPFILEHEADER)BmpFileData;
    PBITMAPINFOHEADER  BInfoHeader = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER)&BmpFileData[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];

    BFileHeader->bfType = 0x4D42; // BM
    BFileHeader->bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
    BFileHeader->bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    BInfoHeader->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    BInfoHeader->biPlanes = 1;
    BInfoHeader->biBitCount = 32;
    BInfoHeader->biCompression = BI_RGB;
    BInfoHeader->biHeight = Height;
    BInfoHeader->biWidth = Width;

    RGBTRIPLE *Image = (RGBTRIPLE*)&BmpFileData[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];
    RGBTRIPLE color;
    //pPixels = (RGBQUAD **)new RGBQUAD[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];
    int start = clock();

    HDC CaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DevC);
    HBITMAP CaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(DevC,Width,Height);
    SelectObject(CaptureDC,CaptureBitmap);
    BitBlt(CaptureDC,0,0,Width,Height,DevC,0,0,SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);
    GetDIBits(CaptureDC,CaptureBitmap,0,Height,frame,(LPBITMAPINFO)BInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    int end = clock();

    cout << "it took " << end - start << " to capture a frame" << endl;

    DWORD Junk;
    HANDLE FH = CreateFileA(BmpName,GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,CREATE_ALWAYS,0,0);
    WriteFile(FH,BmpFileData,FileSize,&Junk,0);
    CloseHandle(FH);
    GlobalFree(BmpFileData); 
}

void video_encode_example(const char *filename, int codec_id)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y, got_output;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

    printf("Encode video file %s\n", filename);

    /* find the mpeg1 video encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        cin.get();
        exit(1);
    }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        cin.get();
        exit(1);
    }

    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 352;
    c->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    c->time_base.num=1;
    c->time_base.den = 25;
    c->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
    c->max_b_frames=1;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if(codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width  = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;

    /* the image can be allocated by any means and av_image_alloc() is
    just the most convenient way if av_malloc() is to be used */
    ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, c->width, c->height, c->pix_fmt, 32);

    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate raw picture buffer\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* encode 1 second of video */
    for(i=0;i<250;i++) {
        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
        pkt.size = 0;

        fflush(stdout);
        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for(y=0;y<c->height;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width;x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }

        /* Cb and Cr */
        for(y=0;y<c->height/2;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width/2;x++) {
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }

        frame->pts = i;

        /* encode the image */
        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (got_output) {
            printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
            fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
            av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
    }

    /* get the delayed frames */
    for (got_output = 1; got_output; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);

        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, NULL, &got_output);

        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (got_output) {
            printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
            fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
            av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
    }

    /* add sequence end code to have a real mpeg file */
    fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), f);
    fclose(f);

     avcodec_close(c);
     av_free(c);
     av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
     av_frame_free(&frame);
     printf("\n");
}

void write_video_frame()
{
}

int lineSizeOfFrame(int width)
{
    return  (width*24 + 31)/32 * 4;//((width*24 / 8) + 3) & ~3;//(width*24 + 31)/32 * 4;
}

int getScreenshotWithCursor(uint8_t* frame)
{
    int successful = 0;
        HDC screen, bitmapDC;
        HBITMAP screen_bitmap;

        screen = GetDC(NULL);
        RECT DesktopParams;

        HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
        GetWindowRect(desktop, &DesktopParams);

        int width = DesktopParams.right;
        int height = DesktopParams.bottom;

        bitmapDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screen);
        screen_bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screen, width, height);
        SelectObject(bitmapDC, screen_bitmap);
        if (BitBlt(bitmapDC, 0, 0, width, height, screen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY))
        {
                int pos_x, pos_y;
                HICON hcur;
                ICONINFO icon_info;
                CURSORINFO cursor_info;
                cursor_info.cbSize = sizeof(CURSORINFO);
                if (GetCursorInfo(&cursor_info))
                {
                        if (cursor_info.flags == CURSOR_SHOWING)
                        {
                                hcur = CopyIcon(cursor_info.hCursor);
                                if (GetIconInfo(hcur, &icon_info))
                                {
                                        pos_x = cursor_info.ptScreenPos.x - icon_info.xHotspot;
                                        pos_y = cursor_info.ptScreenPos.y - icon_info.yHotspot;
                                        DrawIcon(bitmapDC, pos_x, pos_y, hcur);
                                        if (icon_info.hbmColor) DeleteObject(icon_info.hbmColor);
                                        if (icon_info.hbmMask) DeleteObject(icon_info.hbmMask);
                                }
                        }
                }
                int header_size = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 256*sizeof(RGBQUAD);
                size_t line_size = lineSizeOfFrame(width);
                PBITMAPINFO lpbi = (PBITMAPINFO) malloc(header_size);
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biSize = header_size;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = height*line_size;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
                lpbi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
                if (GetDIBits(bitmapDC, screen_bitmap, 0, height, (LPVOID)frame, lpbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
                {
                    int i;
                    uint8_t *buf_begin = frame;
                    uint8_t *buf_end = frame + line_size*(lpbi->bmiHeader.biHeight - 1);
                    void *temp = malloc(line_size);
                    for (i = 0; i < lpbi->bmiHeader.biHeight / 2; ++i)
                    {
                        memcpy(temp, buf_begin, line_size);
                        memcpy(buf_begin, buf_end, line_size);
                        memcpy(buf_end, temp, line_size);
                        buf_begin += line_size;
                        buf_end -= line_size;
                    }
                    cout << *buf_begin << endl;
                    free(temp);
                    successful = 1;
                }
                free(lpbi);
        }
        DeleteObject(screen_bitmap);
        DeleteDC(bitmapDC);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen);
        return successful;
}

int main()
{
    RECT DesktopParams;

    HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    GetWindowRect(desktop, &DesktopParams);

    int width = DesktopParams.right;
    int height = DesktopParams.bottom;
    uint8_t *frame = (uint8_t *)malloc(width * height);

    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *codecContext = NULL;
    AVPacket packet;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *pictureYUV = NULL;
    AVFrame *pictureRGB;

    avcodec_register_all();

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

    if(!codec)
    {
        cout << "codec not found!" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "codec h265 found!" << endl;
    }

    codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

    codecContext->bit_rate = width * height * 4;
    codecContext->width = width;
    codecContext->height = height;
    codecContext->time_base.num = 1;
    codecContext->time_base.den = 250;
    codecContext->gop_size = 10;
    codecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
    codecContext->keyint_min = 1;
    codecContext->i_quant_factor = (float)0.71;                        // qscale factor between P and I frames
    codecContext->b_frame_strategy = 20;                               ///// find out exactly what this does
    codecContext->qcompress = (float)0.6;                              ///// find out exactly what this does
    codecContext->qmin = 20;                                           // minimum quantizer
    codecContext->qmax = 51;                                           // maximum quantizer
    codecContext->max_qdiff = 4;                                       // maximum quantizer difference between frames
    codecContext->refs = 4;                                            // number of reference frames
    codecContext->trellis = 1;
    codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    codecContext->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    codecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

    if(avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL) < 0)
    {
        cout << "couldn't open codec" << endl;
        cout << stderr << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "opened h265 codec!" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    f = fopen("test.h264", "wb");

    if(!f)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }



    struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(codecContext->width, codecContext->height, PIX_FMT_RGB32, codecContext->width, 
        codecContext->height, codecContext->pix_fmt, SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    int got_output = 0, i = 0;
    uint8_t encode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

    try
    {
        for(i = 0; i < codecContext->time_base.den; i++)
        {
            av_init_packet(&packet);
            packet.data = NULL;
            packet.size = 0;

            pictureRGB = av_frame_alloc();
            pictureYUV = av_frame_alloc();

            getScreenshotWithCursor(frame);
            //ScreenShot("example.bmp", frame);

            int nbytes = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);                                    // allocating outbuffer
            uint8_t* outbuffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(nbytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

            pictureRGB = av_frame_alloc();
            pictureYUV = av_frame_alloc();

            avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)pictureRGB, frame, PIX_FMT_RGB32, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);                   // fill image with input screenshot
            avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)pictureYUV, outbuffer, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);
            av_image_alloc(pictureYUV->data, pictureYUV->linesize, codecContext->width, codecContext->height, codecContext->pix_fmt, 32);

            sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, pictureRGB->data, pictureRGB->linesize, 0, codecContext->height, pictureYUV->data, pictureYUV->linesize);

            pictureYUV->pts = i;

            avcodec_encode_video2(codecContext, &packet, pictureYUV, &got_output);

            if(got_output)
            {
                printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, packet.size);
                fwrite(packet.data, 1, packet.size, f);
                av_free_packet(&packet);
            }

            //av_frame_free(&pictureRGB);
            //av_frame_free(&pictureYUV);
        }

        for(got_output = 1; got_output; i++)
        {
            fflush(stdout);

            avcodec_encode_video2(codecContext, &packet, NULL, &got_output);

            if (got_output) {
                printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, packet.size);
                fwrite(packet.data, 1, packet.size, f);
                av_free_packet(&packet);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    avcodec_close(codecContext);
    av_free(codecContext);
    av_freep(&pictureYUV->data[0]);
    //av_frame_free(&picture);
    fwrite(encode, 1, sizeof(encode), f);
    fclose(f);

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what each row in the Pixel Array is padded to a multiple of 4 bytes in size. It is feature of BMP format.

Comment: I did solve this a while back, if I remember correctly it had to do with not capturing the desktop correctly. Now I am having issues sending nal packets across the wire with winsock.